# Strange Chapter Style in Hoefler Text

Tags: fonts, xetex, hoefler

Does anyone know why the bibliography appears as in the picture when using Hoefler Text (and how to fix it)?

[image]

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}    
\section{References}
\end{document}
```

Addendum: Let's ask this differently. Suppose I wanted to specify which font XeLaTeX should use for bold faces. Which command should I use?

Comment: What class are you using? And how do you produce the bibliography?

Comment: This is the [Engraved Capitals](http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_features.php?featureID=33&productLineID=100010) set. Try removing the Alternates.

Comment: A note: you should use `4\textsuperscript{th}`, preferably with the `xltxtra` or `realscripts` package loaded.

Comment: Uh, how do I remove the alternates?

Comment: I really need a code answer to this one :-)

Comment: You have tried to remove the code snippet `Alternate=1`, haven't you?

Comment: @lockstep: of course...

Comment: Here's an even more minimal example, still exhibiting the same behavior. I actually have the full Hoefler Text installed on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font setting should be:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFeatures={Alternate=0,
            Contextuals={NoLineFinal,NoLineInitial}}, 
            Ligatures={Common,Historic},Alternate=1,
            BoldFont=Hoefler Text Black]{Hoefler Text}
```

then I have no problem with xelatex.

the fonts in the pdf:

```
voss@shania:~/Documents> pdffonts latex6.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
DUZIVX+HoeflerText-Black             CID TrueType      yes yes yes      5  0
VLJLSS+HoeflerText-Regular           CID TrueType      yes yes yes      7  0
```

Comment: I updated the minimal working example, and it still uses the engraved fonts :-(

Comment: For some reason, XeLaTeX uses the first variant it finds for bold. If I disable Engraved in my system, it will use Fleurons, and so on...

Comment: Also no problem. I've posted the file list

Comment: Suppose I wanted to specify which font XeLaTeX should use for bold faces. Which command should I use?

Comment: `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,
             BoldFont=Hoefler Text Black]{Hoefler Text}`

Comment: There you go :-) Do you mind adding an answer with that so I can accept it? :-)

Comment: @Hugo: I added it into my answer

Comment: @Hugo: Don't forget to assign also the bounty to the question before it runs out (still 3 days left), otherwise only half of it will be awarded automatically and the rest simply expires. I'm note sure, but you might still need to wait a certain time before you can award it.